# Компиляция в Win 10 для Win 7

Tags: windows

Хочу обновиться попробовать Win 10. Занимаюсь разработкой софта который используется в родной семерочке и вообще не понятно будет ли то что скомпилировано в win 10 правильно работать в win 7. Хотя как должно) Компилятор Visual Studio Community 2015.

Comment: Будет, будет. Выставьте правильный таргет. Если это C#, выставьте правильный фреймворк .NET. И компилируйтесь под десктоп, а не под UWP/Win8 и т. п.

Comment: Только не забудьте отинсталлировать Redistributable на вашей семёрке.

Answer (score 1):

Если это не UWP приложение, а WinForms или консольное, то все будет работать